# Logic Apps custom action similar to Request Response

Tags: webhooks, azure-logic-apps, connector

Is it possible to create a Logic Apps custom action similar to the Request Response action? If so, can you please guide me how I would do this? The Request Response action is different from other actions as it doesn't call an API, but instead responds to the trigger.

I'd like to create a specific version of the Request Response action that forces a certain status code and response structure, so that people using the connector understand how to use it. The action is to be used in conjunction with a custom trigger, which is basically a webhook. The API that call the webhook requires the response to be in a specific format. Right now I can make it work with the Request Response action, but I need to make sure I return the correct JSON structure.

Comment: Check the [HTTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http) and [HTTP Webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-webhook), if these could help you?

Comment: @GeorgeChen thanks for your suggestion. I am aware of the HTTP and HTTP Webhook. I'm trying to create a higher level trigger and action specific to my scenario, with specific input fields required for my API. I know how to build the trigger part. I'm now looking for a way to create a specific response action.

Answer (score 0):

Update, try [Azure Api-Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/). Otherwise, I would validate that all values are present and if not I would reply which values are missing.

Comment: Thanks AdAstra for the suggestion. This would require the user to enter a schema as well. What I'd like is a custom response action with business specific fields. E.g. if I would require the name of a person and a purchase order id, I would like to have a response actions with two fields: Name and Purchase Order ID. I want to hide for the user authoring the logic app that it's returned in a specific format following some schema that my API requires.